# Fetch array data from inside function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently trying to use an array that I have populated inside a function scope. My main problem is that whenever I try to send the array as information, the system tells me it's empty.

Hare are my nested functions:

```
exports.getUserDetails = async function(req ,res ,next){
  try{
      Stats.find({map:"France"}).sort({lapTime:1}).limit(3).then(response =>{
          var resultArray=[]; // <----Here is where I've innitialised my array
          for(var item = 0; item < response.length; item++){
                const singleDriverId = response[item].driver;
                const playedMap = response[item].map; // single Map etry from the stats Object
                const timedLap = response[item].lapTime; //single lapTime entry from the stats Object

                User.find({"_id" : singleDriverId}, function(err, result){
                  if (err) throw err;
                  for (var i = 0; i< result.length; i++){

                   //setting up the Object to populate the Array.
                    var finalResult = {
                        "driver": result[i].firstName + " " + result[i].lastName,
                        "map": playedMap,
                        "laptime": timedLap
                      }
                      //<------populating the Array
                      resultArray.push(finalResult);
                    }
                  });
            }
            console.log(resultArray) // prints an empty Array []
            res.status(200).json({status: 200, data: resultArray, message: "Successfully got the user details."});
        })   
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400);
    }
}
```

I think that somehow `resultArray.push(finalResult);` "empties" before I get the chance to print it?

Does anybody have any suggestions why this is happening and how can I fix it ?

> I am trying to receive a single Array from the `resultArray.push(finalResult)`

Comment: what's `User.find`? It's probably async

Comment: This is a common misconseption in JS.  Your console.log is executed _before_ your code pushes the results into the array.  The User.find operation is async, so the function within that is only executed once the results are available, and definately after the rest of the code ends.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589983/nodejs-capture-response-from-api-call/54590547#54590547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic example of your problem (asynchronous nature of javascript)

```js
function getData(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(Date.now()), Math.random() * 1000);
}


const result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  getData((data) => {
    result.push(data);
  });
}

console.log(result); // empty :O
```

generic solution (run `done` when all is done):

```js
function getData(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(Date.now()), Math.random() * 1000);
}


const result = [];
const count = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  getData((data) => {
    result.push(data);
    done();
  });
}

var called = 0;
function done() {
  called++;
  if (called === count) {
    console.log(result);  // desired result \O/
  }

}
```

Of course now everything is much simpler with promises and async/await (with async/await it looks almost like a synchronous code). There are multiple articles and tuts how to use them.

For your code it should be something like this (be aware that when you do network requests, responses may not come in the same order as requests were sent so the items in `resultArray` may not correspond exactly to items from response):

```
exports.getUserDetails = async function(req ,res ,next){
  try{
      Stats.find({map:"France"}).sort({lapTime:1}).limit(3).then(response =>{
          var resultArray=[]; // <----Here is where I've innitialised my array
          for(var item = 0; item < response.length; item++){
                const singleDriverId = response[item].driver;
                const playedMap = response[item].map; // single Map etry from the stats Object
                const timedLap = response[item].lapTime; //single lapTime entry from the stats Object

                User.find({"_id" : singleDriverId}, function(err, result){
                  if (err) throw err;
                  for (var i = 0; i< result.length; i++){

                   //setting up the Object to populate the Array.
                    var finalResult = {
                        "driver": result[i].firstName + " " + result[i].lastName,
                        "map": playedMap,
                        "laptime": timedLap
                      }
                      //<------populating the Array
                      resultArray.push(finalResult);
                      done(); // function is run whenever data is pushed
                    }
                  });
            }
            var count = 0;
            function done() {
              count++;
              if (count === response.length) { // this code block is run only when all items are pushed into the resultArray
                console.log(resultArray) 
              }
            }
            res.status(200).json({status: 200, data: resultArray, message: "Successfully got the user details."});
        })   
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400);
    }
}
```

Probably `User.find` also supports promises so a simpler and more readable way with the use of `Promise.all` would be a preferable.

Comment: yes this seems to be issue but I am not sure how to apply the solution to my current problem.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I've updated the answer to account for your specific case

Comment: any good tutorials that you can suggest, except the firefox mdn ones?

Comment: @ZombieChowder https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/README.md#you-dont-know-js-async--performance

Answer (score -1):

simply use if statement, it will work

if(resultArray) {
            console.log(resultArray) // prints an empty Array []
            res.status(200).json({status: 200, data: resultArray, message: "Successfully got the user details."});
}